# AngularJS: Is it possible for me to use the codemirror along with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, codemirror

I have a requirement where I have to let the user write some code from my application. I wanted to use Code Mirror library (https://codemirror.net/). My application is developed using AngularJS as the main framework with NO JQuery or any other libraries.

Is it possible for me to use the Code Mirror along with the AngularJS? If yes, can someone show light on how to do it?

Thanking you

Comment: yes you surely can. here's a directive you can use: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-codemirror/

Comment: Thank you.. it worked.. but my font is ariel.. tried changing it using stylesheet...

.CodeMirror {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  font-family: Courier New ,
}

But does not work

Comment: That should have worked. try applying !important rule to font-family.